# Как исправить анимацию блеска кнопки?

Tags: html, css

[image: полупрозрачная область больше кнопки и начинает двигаться очень далеко от кнопки]

Сделал анимацию, но она отображается не корректно, как сделать блеск именно по кнопке?

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, blue);
}

body {
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button-m {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 76px;
  line-height: 76px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  border: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #222222;
  background: rgba(253, 220, 64, 0.1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(253, 220, 64, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 193, 1, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(253, 220, 64, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 193, 1, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(253, 220, 64, 1)), to(rgba(255, 193, 1, 1)));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(253, 220, 64, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 193, 1, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(253, 220, 64, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 193, 1, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(253, 220, 64, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 193, 1, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fddc40', endColorstr='#ffc101', GradientType=0);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #d7a200;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #d7a200;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #d7a200;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0#ffe58b;
}

@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    left: -230%;
    top: -20%;
  }
  50% {
    left: -50%;
    top: -50%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -230%;
    top: -20%;
  }
}

.button-m:after {
  .... animation: anim 2s infinite;
}

.button-m:after {
  content: "";
  height: 200%;
  left: -230%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20%;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
  width: 200%;
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13);
  background: linear-gradient( to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13) 77%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 92%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%);
  animation: anim 2s infinite;
}

.button-m:active:after {
  opacity: 0;
}

.button-m:hover {
  background: rgb(253, 223, 71);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(253, 223, 71, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 194, 9, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(253, 223, 71, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 194, 9, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(253, 223, 71, 1)), to(rgba(255, 194, 9, 1)));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(253, 223, 71, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 194, 9, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(253, 223, 71, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 194, 9, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(253, 223, 71, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 194, 9, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fddf47', endColorstr='#ffc209', GradientType=0);
}

.button-m:active {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #d7a200;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #d7a200;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #d7a200;
  top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#order_form" class="button-m">Оформить заказ</a>
```

Comment: по кнопке, это значит по нажатию?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ нет, чтобы корректно в зоне самой кнопки происходила анимация, а сейчас она сбоку и больше области самой кнопки

Comment: приложите скрин, что Вам не нравится, по словесному описанию - не понятно или я вижу не то что Вы

Comment: Вы скопировали многоточие из прошлого ответа, так делать не надо, им я хотел показать все другие свойства которые у Вас уже есть

Comment: @StrangerintheQ добавил скриншот, полупрозразначная зона явно больше чем сама кнопка и начинает двигаться далеко от самой кнопки, как исправить, чтобы она была по высоте кнопки, меньшей ширины и начинала движение строго с начала кнопки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.button-m {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, blue);
}

body {
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button-m {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 76px;
  line-height: 76px;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  border: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #222222;
  background: rgba(253, 220, 64, 0.1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(253, 220, 64, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 193, 1, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(253, 220, 64, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 193, 1, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(253, 220, 64, 1)), to(rgba(255, 193, 1, 1)));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(253, 220, 64, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 193, 1, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(253, 220, 64, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 193, 1, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(253, 220, 64, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 193, 1, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fddc40', endColorstr='#ffc101', GradientType=0);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #d7a200;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #d7a200;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #d7a200;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0#ffe58b;
}

@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    left: -230%;
    top: -20%;
  }
  50% {
    left: -50%;
    top: -50%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -230%;
    top: -20%;
  }
}

.button-m:after {
  .... animation: anim 2s infinite;
}

.button-m:after {
  content: "";
  height: 200%;
  left: -230%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20%;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
  width: 200%;
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13);
  background: linear-gradient( to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.13) 77%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 92%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0) 100%);
  animation: anim 2s infinite;
}

.button-m:active:after {
  opacity: 0;
}

.button-m:hover {
  background: rgb(253, 223, 71);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(253, 223, 71, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 194, 9, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(253, 223, 71, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 194, 9, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(253, 223, 71, 1)), to(rgba(255, 194, 9, 1)));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(253, 223, 71, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 194, 9, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(253, 223, 71, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 194, 9, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(253, 223, 71, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 194, 9, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fddf47', endColorstr='#ffc209', GradientType=0);
}

.button-m:active {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #d7a200;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #d7a200;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #d7a200;
  top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#order_form" class="button-m">Оформить заказ</a>
```